# Homotopy equivalance of disk and point

Tags: general-topology

I've just started out with learning basic topology, and I'm a bit puzzled bit the following "proof" or "example" in the notes I'm reading. The definition of *homotopy equivalence* (~) has just been stated before this example.

---

Take the two spaces $D$, the disk and $P$, a point. The two spaces are *homotopy equivalent*.

Proof: We let $\forall \alpha \in D$, $f(\alpha) = P$ and $g(P)$ be some point in $D$, say the center $C$. Clearly $(f \circ g)(P) = P$, and therefore $f \circ g \simeq I_y$.

For $g \circ f$, we now have $(g \circ f)(\alpha) = C$. $\color{red}{\text{Radial retraction shows that the map } g \circ f \text{ is homotopic to } I_x.}$

---

1. I don't fully understand what the red line means.
2. I don't fully understand why it shows that $g \circ f \simeq I_x$.

Is it because we can "deform" $I_x$ into a map that maps every point in $D$ to $C$?

I realise this is probably very basic, so sorry about that. But I fear I am missing some fundamental understanding that would probably be a good idea to get before I move on.

Thanks!

Comment: Radial retraction roughly means that you shrink the disk along lines through the origin. So you continuosly shrink it by letting every point slide along the line through that point and the origin (center).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence regarding radial retraction is a hint to your intuition. Your own sentence on deforming $I_x$ is also a nice hint.

These hints should prod the reader to write down a formula for a homotopy between the two maps $g \circ f :D \to D$ and $I_D : D \to D$ (I prefer to denote it $I_D$ rather than $I_x$, using the subscript to tell me that this is the identity map on the space $D$).

To start with, those two maps have their own simple formulas:
$$g \circ f(\alpha)=C
$$
$$I_D(\alpha)=\alpha
$$
The following formula gives the desired homotopy from $g \circ f$ to $I_D$, visualization of which will show that "radial retraction" is a perfect two word description:
$$H(\alpha,t) = (1-t)C + t \alpha
$$

Comment: Yes I see, that makes sense. Thank you!